# Nodejs stream pausing (unpipe) and resume (pipe) intermediate pipe

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, node.js-stream

I need to "pause" a readable stream for a certain number of seconds and resume it again. The readable stream is being piped to a transform stream, so I cannot use the regular `pause` and `resume` methods, I had to use `unpipe` and `pipe`. In the transform stream, I am able to detect the `pipe` event and then do `unpipe` on the readable stream, then after a number of seconds, do `pipe` again to resume it (I hope).

Here is the code:

### main.ts

```
import {Transform, Readable} from 'stream';

const alphaTransform = new class extends Transform {
    constructor() {
        super({
            objectMode: true,
            transform: (chunk: string | Buffer, encoding: string, callback: Function) => {
                let transformed: IterableIterator<string>;
                if (Buffer.isBuffer(chunk)) {
                    transformed = function* () {
                        for (const val of chunk) {
                            yield String.fromCharCode(val);
                        }
                    }();
                } else {
                    transformed = chunk[Symbol.iterator]();
                }
                callback(null,
                    Array.from(transformed).map(s => s.toUpperCase()).join(''));
            }
        });
    }
}

const spyingAlphaTransformStream =  new class extends Transform {
    private oncePaused = false;

    constructor() {
        super({
            transform: (chunk: string | Buffer, encoding: string, callback: Function) => {
                console.log('Before transform:');
                if (Buffer.isBuffer(chunk)) {
                    console.log(chunk.toString('utf-8'));
                    alphaTransform.write(chunk);
                } else {
                    console.log(chunk);
                    alphaTransform.write(chunk, encoding);
                }
                callback(null, alphaTransform.read());
            }
        });

        this.on('pipe', (src: Readable) => {
            if (!this.oncePaused) {
                src.unpipe(this); // Here I unpipe the readable stream
                console.log(`Data event listeners count: ${src.listeners('data').length}`);
                console.log(`Readable state of reader: ${src.readable}`);
                console.log("We paused the reader!!");
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.oncePaused = true;
                    src.pipe(this); // Here I resume it...hopefully?
                    src.resume();
                    console.log("We unpaused the reader!!");
                    console.log(`Data event listeners count: ${src.listeners('data').length}`);
                    console.log(`Readable state of reader: ${src.readable}`);
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

        this.on('data', (transformed) => {
            console.log('After transform:\n', transformed);
        });
    }
}

const reader = new class extends Readable {
    constructor(private content?: string | Buffer) {
        super({
            read: (size?: number) => {
                if (!this.content) {
                    this.push(null);
                } else {
                    this.push(this.content.slice(0, size));
                    this.content = this.content.slice(size);
                }
            }
        });
    }
} (new Buffer('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\n'));

reader.pipe(spyingAlphaTransformStream)
    .pipe(process.stdout);
```

The problem is with the middle stream `spyingAlphaTransformStream`. This is the one that listens for the pipe event and then pauses and resumes the readable stream after `1 second`. The problem is that after it unpipes the  readable stream, and then pipes from it again, nothing is written to the standard output, which means that the `transform` method of the `spyingAlphaTransformStream` is never called which means something is broken in the stream.

I expect the output to look something like:

```
Data event listeners count: 0
Readable state of reader: true
We paused the reader!!
We unpaused the reader!!
Data event listeners count: 1
Readable state of reader: true
Before transform:
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

After transform:
 THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.

THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.
```

But it actually looks like:

```
Data event listeners count: 0
Readable state of reader: true
We paused the reader!!
We unpaused the reader!!
Data event listeners count: 1
Readable state of reader: true
```

Basically nothing is being piped *from* the readable is what I can conclude from that.

How can I fix this?

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-stream",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build:live",
    "build:live": "nodemon"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "typescript",
    "nodejs",
    "ts-node",
    "cli",
    "node",
    "hello"
  ],
  "license": "WTFPL",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^7.0.21",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.4",
    "typescript": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

### nodemon.json

```
{
    "ignore": ["node_modules"],
    "delay": "2000ms",
    "execMap": {
        "ts": "ts-node"
    },
    "runOnChangeOnly": false,
    "verbose": true
}
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was surprisingly simpler than I had expected. What I had to do was to find a way to defer any callbacks done in the `transform` method, and wait till the stream was "ready" before calling the initial callback.

Basically, in the `spyingAlphaTransformStream` constructor, I had a boolean value checking whether the stream was ready, and if it wasn't, I stored a callback in the class which will execute the first callback I received in the `transform` method. *Now since that first callback was not executed, **the stream does not receive further calls*** i.e. there is only ever one pending callback to worry about; so it was now simply a waiting game until the stream indicates it was ready (this is done with a simple `setTimeout`).

When the stream is "ready", I set the ready boolean to true, then I call the pending callback (if set) and at this point, flow continues throughout the entire stream.

I have a longer example to show how this works:

```
import {Transform, Readable} from 'stream';

const alphaTransform = new class extends Transform {
    constructor() {
        super({
            objectMode: true,
            transform: (chunk: string | Buffer, encoding: string, callback: Function) => {
                let transformed: IterableIterator<string>;
                if (Buffer.isBuffer(chunk)) {
                    transformed = function* () {
                        for (const val of chunk) {
                            yield String.fromCharCode(val);
                        }
                    }();
                } else {
                    transformed = chunk[Symbol.iterator]();
                }
                callback(null,
                    Array.from(transformed).map(s => s.toUpperCase()).join(''));
            }
        });
    }
}

class LoggingStream extends Transform {
    private pending: () => void;
    private isReady = false;

    constructor(message: string) {
        super({
            objectMode: true,
            transform: (chunk: string | Buffer, encoding: string, callback: Function) => {
                if (!this.isReady) { // ready flag
                    this.pending = () => { // create a pending callback
                        console.log(message);
                        if (Buffer.isBuffer(chunk)) {
                            console.log(`[${new Date().toTimeString()}]: ${chunk.toString('utf-8')}`);
                        } else {
                            console.log(`[${new Date().toTimeString()}]: ${chunk}`);
                        }
                        callback(null, chunk);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log(message);
                    if (Buffer.isBuffer(chunk)) {
                        console.log(`[${new Date().toTimeString()}]: ${chunk.toString('utf-8')}`);
                    } else {
                        console.log(`[${new Date().toTimeString()}]: ${chunk}`);
                    }
                    callback(null, chunk);
                }
            }
        });

        this.on('pipe', this.pauseOnPipe);
    }

    private pauseOnPipe() {
        this.removeListener('pipe', this.pauseOnPipe);
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.isReady = true; // set ready flag to true
            if (this.pending) { // execute pending callbacks (if any) 
                this.pending();
            }
        }, 3000); // wait three seconds
    }
}

const reader = new class extends Readable {
    constructor(private content?: string | Buffer) {
        super({
            read: (size?: number) => {
                if (!this.content) {
                    this.push(null);
                } else {
                    this.push(this.content.slice(0, size));
                    this.content = this.content.slice(size);
                }
            }
        });
    }
} (new Buffer('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\n'));

reader.pipe(new LoggingStream("Before transformation:"))
    .pipe(alphaTransform)
    .pipe(new LoggingStream("After transformation:"))
    .pipe(process.stdout);
```

### Output

```
<Waits about 3 seconds...>

Before transformation:
[11:13:53 GMT-0600 (CST)]: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

After transformation:
[11:13:53 GMT-0600 (CST)]: THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.

THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.
```

*Note since JS is single threaded, both verbose streams wait the same amount of time before continuing*